# Remove Preference based on the value of another Preference in Android

Tags: java, android

My question is about dynamic (shared)preferences in Android. I have searched a lot but can't find a proper solution.

I have a `SwitchPreference` which should add or remove an `EditTextPreference` according to its value.

Therefore I have a *SettingsFragment.java* class:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = "SteuerApp Fragment";

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Einsttelungsseite aus XML-Datei laden
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Log.v(TAG, "If-Schleife");
    if(findPreference("industrial_tax").equals(false)){
        Log.v(TAG, "If-Schleife");
        Preference residence = findPreference("residence");
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        preferenceScreen.removePreference(residence);
    }


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); //register SharedPreference
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); //unregister SharedPreference
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

The XML layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/calc_base">
...
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="industrial_tax"
            android:title="@string/industrial_tax"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/residence"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="residence"
            android:title="@string/residence" />
...
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I tried debugging, but it never enters the if-clause, and I can't figure out why...

Isn't a `SwitchPreference` binary? I am new to Android and try not to bother you guys unnecessarily, but I am really at an dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findPreference()` returns a `Preference` object (or `null`).

The problem is you're checking equality between this `Preference` object and the `boolean` value `false`. The `if` block will never be executed.

`SwitchPreference` has the `isChecked()` method (inherited from `TwoStatePreference`), you might want to use that instead:

```
// get ahold of the SwitchPreference instance
SwitchPreference pref = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("industrial_tax");

// if it's not checked, then remove the corresponding Preference
if (!pref.isChecked()) {
    Log.v(TAG, "If-Schleife");

    Preference residence = findPreference("residence");
    getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(residence);
}
```

Also, if you're ok with just disabling the `Preference` rather than removing it, then using the [`android:dependency`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:dependency) attribute might be a simpler/cleaner approach:

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="industrial_tax"
    android:title="@string/industrial_tax"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:dependency="industrial_tax"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/residence"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:key="residence"
    android:title="@string/residence" />
```